# How and why, to add the details of an installed product to System Registry, while creating setUp project for C# windows application?

Tags: c#, registry, setup-project, setup-deployment, registrykey

I have added setUp project to My C# windows application. But did not register it with system registry. It dawned on me that to register it with system registry one has to follow the followin procedure:
  I overrided the "Install" method with the following code:

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
  base.Install(stateSaver);
  RegistrationServices regSrv = new RegistrationServices();
  regSrv.RegisterAssembly(base.GetType().Assembly,
    AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
}
```

Similiarly adding the following code to overridden Unistall method.

```
public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
  base.Uninstall(savedState);
  RegistrationServices regSrv = new RegistrationServices();
  regSrv.UnregisterAssembly(base.GetType().Assembly);
}
```

Is this fine to add the above code snippets to install & uninstall methods. Since, registry manipulations may lead to system crash I didnt do this.

> Can someone kindly let me know the
>   exact procedure to register an
>   installation with system registry.
>   Also what is the advantage of registering while installation.

**I am totally new to registry manipulation while coding. I want to learn from basics of what is meant by registry, registry_key,GUID,ClassId and other important setails related to registry manipulations.in greater detail. Can anyone kindly suggest me some material for this.**
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for registering the assembly into registry is for exposing it to any old COM style applications which use your assembly. Unless you have any such specific need, you should avoid messing about with the registry at all, in my opinion.

If your application assemblies are not shared, no need for any registration.
If they are shared with other .NET applications, the recommended mechanism for doing it is via the GAC.

Comment: If I need to register my Windows application installation with registry than is it appropriate to use the above code snippets.?

Comment: @engineerMaster - This code snippet that you have given above does look all right to me. However, since i have not used it before, I hence did not comment on that aspect of your question.